Expected Number of Coin Tosses Until n-th Head or n-th Tail
I'm working on finding the expected number of coin tosses required until either the $n$-th head or $n$-th tail appears, whichever comes first. The coin is fair, so the probability of heads or tails is $0.5$.
Problem Setup
Let $E$ represent the expected number of tosses needed. I have formulated the expectation using the probability that the sequence reaches the $n$-th head or tail on the $(n + i)$-th toss:

For the $(n + i)$-th toss to be the first time we reach $n$ heads or tails, the probability is:
$$
   P(\text{first reaches } n \text{ heads or tails at } n+i) = \frac{1}{2^{n+i-1}} \binom{n+i-1}{i}
   $$

Then, the expected value $E$ can be expressed as:
$$
   E = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^{n+i-1}} \binom{n+i-1}{i} \cdot (n+i)
   $$


Where I'm Stuck
This setup seems reasonable to me, but I'm having trouble simplifying this summation to get a closed-form expression for $E$, if one exists. I suspect that generating functions or other advanced techniques might be helpful here, but I’m unsure of the next steps.
Is this approach valid? And if so, does anyone have any insights on how to simplify this summation?
Edit
I just realize I can rewrite the formula into:
$$
   E = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^{n+i-1}} \binom{n+i-1}{i} \cdot (n+i) = n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^{n+i-1}} \binom{n+i}{i} = 2n \big[\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{1}{2^{n+i}} \binom{n+i}{i} -  \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}} \binom{2n}{n} \big] = 2n(1 - \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}} \binom{2n}{n}) \approx 2(n -\sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi}}),
   $$
where this part $$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{1}{2^{n+i}} \binom{n+i}{i} = 1$$ because it is the sum of all the probabilities for case $n+1$. Please let me know if this reasoning is correct of flawed

Yeah you are right. I just fixed it - although it sort off cancels out with using the probability = 1 argument to simplify
